# How to transfer data from a csv with multiple/single delimiter to postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, delimiter

Hi I have a dataset in CSV. I want to import it into Postgre DB in a peculiar format 
The data in the CSV is in following format.

```
1::comedy*drama*horror
2::suspense*thriller
```

Now I want to import this in a Postgre table having two columns id and genre, where id is a foreign key as :

```
id  genre
1   comedy
1   drama
1   horror
2   suspense
2   thriller
```

Appreciate your help thanks!

Comment: You have to process the file externally before import

Comment: That's not CSV at all, it's something else entirely. Use a tool designed to consume that data and produce real CSV (or to insert it directly into a DB). Maybe an ETL tool can help? CloverETL, Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle. But personally I'd use perl/python/whatever, reading the data, processing it into sane CSV, and feeding it into PostgreSQL with `COPY`.